# Python3 objects passing from functions

Tags: class, object, python-3.x, linked-list

The below code snippet is for deleting a node in linked list. My class contains two members namely `data` and `next` a pointer to hold other objects of that class type. When, I run my program, I don't get any error. If I try to delete the first item in the linked list, it enters the First for loop and displays the message "The data is found". But if I print my list, I am seeing the element in the list. I think this is because of assigning objects back, but I am not able to find where I have done that mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def deleteNode(self, a_data):
        flag = 0


        if (self.data == a_data):
            print("The data is found")
            self = self.next
            flag = 1

        else:

            while(self.next != None):

                if (self.next.data == a_data):

                    self.next = self.next.next
                    flag = 1
                    break

                else:

                    self = self.next

        if(flag):
            print("Data Deleted")
        else:
            print("Data not available")
```

Thanks

Comment: I guess you're assigning your list to a variable, then modify it with your function and then look at it again. If that's right i can provide an answer.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu Thanks for reply. I modified my function to return the reference itself.

Comment: That's what i would have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`self = self.next` in your code has no effect on the outside world: it just assigns to a *local* variable.

It looks like you are trying to delete a node from within Node class itself. You could use a function instead that accepts a list head and returns a (possibly new) list head with the corresponding item deleted:

```
def delete_node(head, data):
    """Delete the first node in the `head` list that has `data`."""
    prev, node = None, head
    while node is not None: # until the last node (`None` means empty list)
        if node.data == data: # found node that has data
           if prev is None: # we are at the very beginning of the list
              assert head is node
              head = node.next # remove the first node
           else:
              assert prev.next is node
              prev.next = node.next # remove internal node
           break
        prev, node = node, node.next
    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends,

I modified my function. I think the error may be because not assigning back the value to the original one, so I made my function to return value. Comments and other methods and any other reason for above than mine are cordially welcome.

```
def deleteNode(self, a_data):
        flag = 0


        if (self.data == a_data):
            print("The data is found")
            self = self.next
            flag = 1

        else:

            while(self.next != None):

                if (self.next.data == a_data):

                    self.next = self.next.next
                    flag = 1
                    break

                else:

                    self = self.next

        if(flag):
            print("Data Deleted")
        else:
            print("Data not available")

        return self
```

Thanks
S

Comment: It's right that you need to assign the return value of the function back to the variable. But just like J.F. Sebastian pointed out in his answer it doesn't make to assign something else to self. Because this only affects the namespace of the function.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu Yeah Learnt my lesson on this. Thanks